# How to parse the job status in case of any exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hi I am facing problem in parsing the job status in Spring Batch [ I am new to spring-batch ]. In my ItemReader even though exception is occurring , status shows **COMPLETED**.

this is my job config.

```
@Bean
public Job customerJob(){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("custJob")  
            .listener(jobListner)           
            .start(custStep())              
            .build();

private Step custStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("custStep1")
            .<Customer,Customer>chunk(10)
            .reader(customerItemReader)
            .processor(customerItemProcessor)
            .writer(customerItemWriter)             
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .build();
```

**ItemReader** class

```
@Override
public Customer read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException,
        NonTransientResourceException {

    if(customerList != null && customerList.size() >=1){
        Customer customer;
         customer =  customerList.remove(0);
         System.out.println("@@ ID="+customer.getCustNumber());     


         return customer;
    }
    return null;
}


//Method to fetch list[from ItemStream interface]
@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    System.out.println("reading customer list"); 
    try {
        customerList = customerService.getCustomers();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Here `getCustomers()` method  from line `customerList = customerService.getCustomers()` some time throw `java.net.SocketException` exception (if there is some problem in server). In this case I excepct that my job status should fail, but it shows "COMPLETED".

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    System.out.println("exit status ="+jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    System.out.println(" status ="+jobExecution.getStatus().name());

}
```

---

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    //Line ommited
exit status =COMPLETED
status =COMPLETED
```

How to show status "FAIL" in such case.

Comment: Hmmm, don't catch the exception?

Comment: thanks @Artefacto, I totally missed that. However, instead of not catching the exception, I have thrown new runtimeException in catch block as IOException    is type of checked exception.